# Bitmap rotation issue in android

Tags: android, bitmap, image-rotation

I'am  rotating the background image of screen onclick of a button.

```
Bitmap rotatedBitmap = null;
int curAngle = 0;

private Bitmap rotateImageBitmap(Bitmap org) {      

    if(rotatedBitmap != null  )
    {
        rotatedBitmap.recycle();
    }

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    curAngle += 90;
    matrix.postRotate(curAngle);
    rotatedBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap(org, 0, 0,  org.getWidth(),  org.getHeight(), matrix, true);

    return rotatedBitmap;        
}
```

App is force closing on click of button 5th time. (Image is rotating 4 times) 
Logcat : trying to use a recycled bitmap. Please help me.

Comment: Dont increase curAngle with 90 Every time rotate image with 90 and save the image in the Main Bitmap

Comment: It seems like the bitmap that is getting passed into the method is being recycled.

Answer (score 0):

Max Angle is 360 and when you clicking 5th time your code is setting angle = 450
which is not valid.So try to reset your angle when angle reaches 360 degrees.

Comment: or can do curAngle = curAngle%360 ?

Comment: or can do .. curAngle = (curAngle + 90) % 360 ;

Answer (score 0):

This is from Developer Guide ....

1. Mobile devices typically have constrained system resources. Android devices can have as little as 16MB of memory available to a single application.
2. Bitmaps take up a lot of memory, especially for rich images like photographs. For example, the camera on the Galaxy Nexus takes photos up to 2592x1936 pixels (5 megapixels). If the bitmap configuration used is ARGB_8888 (the default from the Android 2.3 onward) then loading this image into memory takes about 19MB of memory (2592*1936*4 bytes), immediately exhausting the per-app limit on some devices.